# Implementing new InetAddress types in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, network-protocols

today it's about the `InetAddress` class of java. There are 2 default implementations (actually 3 if you take `InetAddressImpl` in count): `Inet4Address` for representing IPv4 addresses and `Inet6Address` for representing IPv6 Addresses.

Now there are several tunneling protocols. Because I want the software to be type safe, I thought about implementing them as subclasses of `InetAddress` (`InetTeredoAddress` or `Inet6to4Address` for example). The best solution would be to inherit from `Inet6Address` but because it is final, this option is dropped. The next idea is to create subclasses of InetAddress and delegate every method to it's `Inet6Address` pendant:

```
class InetTeredoAddress
    extends InetAddress {

    protected Inet6Address address;

    @Override
    public boolean isMulticastAddress() {
        return address.isMulticastAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAnyLocalAddress() {
        return address.isAnyLocalAddress();
    }

    ...
}
```

This, again, fails because its constructors are only visible in java.net.* . Just for fun, I tried to create a package called `java.net` and placed all classes inside. This way I was able to compile but when starting the program, (surprise surprise) the following error occurred

```
org.testng.TestNGException: java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.net
```

What would be the best way to implement the protocols? Or is a Helper class the only solution?

Thanks in advance

Zota

Comment: "tunneling protocols" is a tunnelling protocol really a different kind of Internet address?

Comment: Well not in general no ^^ but in some cases you can get the original IP out of another. For example 6to4: looks something like `2002:1010:1010::` where 1010:1010 is the hex representation of 16.16.16.16, the IPv4 address. So I can define the "real" address just because I'm using some parts of the Tunneling protocol :)

Comment: That is an `Inet6Address`, for which it is possible to define a function that maps it to an `Inet4Address`. Instead of creating a class, you should create a method  `static Inet4Address getTunnelledAddress(Inet6Address)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget it, and set about implementing a family of URLConnectionHandlers instead.

Comment: Thanks, but because I just want to handle the IPs (I don't want to connect or send data or something) URLConnection would be a quite huge approach ;)

Comment: Not really, you only have to write two classes per protocol. I've done it many times. I don't understand what exactly you mean by 'handle the IPs' if it doesn't involve I/O.

Comment: I get several IPs from the database and has to detect if it's using a tunneling protocol and convert it in several parts of the program to its ipv4 version (without loosing the original IP). It's similar to GeoIP requests: you handle the IP but don't transfer something.

Comment: So you just need to tag the addresses in the database.

Comment: well yes and no. This would solve the problem with the detection, but not the conversion part. Therefore I would need a helper class. Anyway, I've created an Interface containing everything. This way, it's easier to add new protocols if necessary. Anyway, for this specific problem, we've found a solution so thank you =)